# Optimising the process of a Huge List<T> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I'm working on a scheduling algorithm that generates/assigns time-slots to a List of Recipients based on the following restrictions:

- Max Recipients per Minute
- Max Recipients per Hour

Suppose that the delivery Start Time is 2018-10-17 9:00 AM and we have 19 recipients with Max of 5 per min and and 10 per hour, so the output should be:

1. 5 Recipients will be scheduled on 2018-10-17 9:00 AM
2. 5 Recipients will be scheduled on 2018-10-17 9:01 AM
3. 5 Recipients will be scheduled on 2018-10-17 10:00 AM
4. 4 Recipients will be scheduled on 2018-10-17 10:01 AM

The algorithm is very accurate, but the way it works is as following:

- First it generates a list of time-slots or time-windows that are accurately fits the no. of recipients based on the restrictions i mentioned before.
- then, I'm moving whatever available in the List of Time-Slots for each set/group or recipients.
- in the list of Time-Slots I added a counter that increments for every recipient added to it, so in this way I can track the no. of each recipients added to each time-slot to respect the Max per Min./Hr restrictions.

The previous process it simplified in this code snippet - I'm using While Loop to iterate, in my case when having 500K recipients this is taking 28 minutes to get it done!
I tried to use Parallel.ForEach but I couldn't figure out how to implement it in this case.

```
DateTime DeliveryStart = DateTime.Now;
//This list has DateTime: Time-windows  values starting from DeliveryStart to the Max value of the time needed to schedule the Recipients
var listOfTimeSlots = new List<Tuple<DateTime, bool, int>>();
//List of Recipients with Two types of data: DateTime to tell when its scheduled and int value refers to the Recipient's ID
var ListOfRecipients = new List<Tuple<DateTime, int>>();
List<Tuple<int, DateTime>> RecipientsWithTimeSlots= new List<Tuple<int, DateTime>>();
int noOfRecipients = ListOfRecipients.Count;

int Prevhour = 0, _AddedPerHour = 0, Prevday = 0;
// Scheduling restrictions 
int _MaxPerHour = 5400, _MaxPerMinute = 90;
int i = 0;
int indexStart = 0;

// ...
//     ...
//           Code to fill listOfTimeSlots ListOfRecipients with Data

while (noOfRecipients > 0)
{
    var TimeStamp = listOfTimeSlots[i];

    int hour = TimeStamp.Item1.Hour;
    int day = TimeStamp.Item1.Day;

    if (Prevhour == 0)
    {
        Prevhour = hour;
        Prevday = day;
    }
    if (Prevhour != hour)
    {
        Prevhour = hour;
        _AddedPerHour = 0;
    }

    if (_AddedPerHour >= _MaxPerHour)
    {
        var tmpItem = listOfTimeSlots.Where(l => l.Item1.Hour == hour && l.Item1.Day == day).LastOrDefault();
        int indexOfNextItem = listOfTimeSlots.LastIndexOf(tmpItem) + 1;
        i = indexOfNextItem;
        _AddedPerHour = 0;
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        int endIndex;


        endIndex = _MaxPerMinute > noOfRecipients ? noOfRecipients : _MaxPerMinute;

        if (endIndex > Math.Abs(_AddedPerHour - _MaxPerHour))
            endIndex = Math.Abs(_AddedPerHour - _MaxPerHour);

        var RecipientsToIteratePerMinute = ListOfRecipients.GetRange(indexStart, endIndex);

        foreach (var item in RecipientsToIteratePerMinute)
        {
            RecipientsWithTimeSlots.Add(new Tuple<int, DateTime>(item.Item2, TimeStamp.Item1));
            listOfTimeSlots[i] = new Tuple<DateTime, bool, int>(TimeStamp.Item1, true, listOfTimeSlots[i].Item3 + 1);
            _AddedPerHour++;
        }

        indexStart += endIndex;
        noOfRecipients -= endIndex;
        i++;

    }
}
```

I simplified the code in here, for not making it so complex to understand, all i want it to speed-up the while loop or replacing it with a Parallel.ForEach.

THE WHILE LOOP IS NEVER SIMPLIFIED, THIS IS HOW IT EXACTLY WORKS \

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right tool for the job here? Seems like something very amenable to set-based processing in an SQL database.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yest C# is the only tool I can use, SQL is not an option in this case - I have to do it only using C# because the algorithm that generates time-slots is also taking care of each recipient's timezone, and we have to take this in to the account, and using .Net we can handle all the available timezones - approx. 138 timezone

Comment: The thing that's taking up time here is memory allocation and nested loops. You need to avoid both for performance. I think depending on what you're doing, I'd take a different approach. If you actually need to know the schedule accurately in advance, use a database to store everything. If you are simply trying to do some type of load balancing, then pick at runtime by running every minute and taking max of items_per_minute. You could also track how many you've done in the past hour, and use that as an additional throttle.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I simplified the code in here, for not making it so complex to understand, all i want it to speed-up the while loop or replacing it with a Parallel.ForEach

Comment: You are assuming `Parallel.ForEach` is the way to fix it. Perhaps there is another way? Hard to tell when you "simplify the code in here".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the problem is that I have to set the scheduled time in advance in a single call, I don't have to re-visit it again, based on the requirements to get it done.
and the time varies and changes in every Campaign that contains this list of Recipients

Comment: Tuple abuse warning. Why are you using Tuples instead of classes with properties that ***have meaningful names***? It makes your code an awful read.

Comment: The simplify was not in the while loop, was just removing the Part that generates the time-slots "this is accurate and I don't need to replace it" @JuanR

Comment: Even with with a list size of 500k I find it hard to believe that this simple loop will run for as long as 28 minutes. I think what actually takes so much time is what you omitted in your example, maybe expensive IO operations?

Comment: It is a quadratic algorithm, gets out of hand quickly.  You need to get rid of the inner loop, a SortedList that is sorted by date/time ought to lessen the blow.

Comment: @spender well, this is a good suggestion, btw this is why I asked in StackOverflow, because I wanted suggestions :) Thanks

Comment: Agreeing with @spender ! Applying C# naming conventions wouldn't hurt the readability. I'm thinking e.g. `var timeSlots = new List<TimeSlot>();` instead of `var listOfTimeSlots = new List<Tuple<DateTime, bool, int>>();`

Comment: @marsze is this going to speed up the while loop or just improve the readability? This is good suggestion and I'll update the code

Comment: While you're on it, provide some example data for timeslots/recipients. It's not easy to try out your code and get why you're trying to do with empty lists.

Comment: @marsze you're right, I'll do it now

Comment: No offense, but your algorithm is very **linear**. A quick glance reveals a good number of repetitive control `if` statements as well as loops. This is usually a sign that the code can be improved with set operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different approach. It creates the groups of ids first, then assigns them the date based on the requirements.

First, a class to represent the groups (avoid them tuples):

```
public class RecipientGroup
{       
    public RecipientGroup(DateTime scheduledDateTime, IEnumerable<int> recipients)
    {
        ScheduledDateTime= scheduledDateTime;
        Recipients = recipients;
    }

    public DateTime ScheduledDateTime { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> Recipients { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format($"Date: {ScheduledDateTime.ToShortDateString()} {ScheduledDateTime.ToLongTimeString()}, count: {Recipients.Count()}");
    }
}
```

Then a class to iterate through the groups. You will see why this is needed later:

```
public class GroupIterator
{        
    public GroupIterator(DateTime scheduledDateTime)
    {
        ScheduledDateTime = scheduledDateTime;
    }

    public DateTime ScheduledDateTime { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the code:

```
DateTime DeliveryStart = new DateTime(2018, 10, 17);
        
//List of Recipients (fake populate function)
IEnumerable<int> allRecipients = PopulateRecipients();            

// Scheduling restrictions 
int maxPerMinute = 90;
int maxPerHour = 270;

//Creates groups broken down by the max per minute.  
var groupsPerMinute = allRecipients
        .Select((s, i) => new { Value = s, Index = i })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / maxPerMinute)
        .Select(group => group.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray());

//This will be the resulting groups
var deliveryDateGroups = new List<RecipientGroup>();

//Perform an aggregate run on the groups using the iterator
groupsPerMinute.Aggregate(new GroupIterator(DeliveryStart), (iterator, ids) => 
{
    var nextBreak = iterator.Count + ids.Count();
    if (nextBreak >= maxPerHour)
    {
        //Will go over limit, split
        var difference = nextBreak-maxPerHour;
        var groupSize = ids.Count() - difference;
        //This group completes the batch
        var group = new RecipientGroup(iterator.ScheduledDateTime, ids.Take(groupSize));
        deliveryDateGroups.Add(group);
        var newDate = iterator.ScheduledDateTime.AddHours(1).AddMinutes(-iterator.ScheduledDateTime.Minute);
        //Add new group with remaining recipients.
        var stragglers = new RecipientGroup(newDate, ids.Skip(groupSize));
        deliveryDateGroups.Add(stragglers);
        return new GroupIterator(newDate, difference);
    }                    
    else
    {
        var group = new RecipientGroup(iterator.ScheduledDateTime, ids);
        deliveryDateGroups.Add(group);
        iterator.ScheduledDateTime = iterator.ScheduledDateTime.AddMinutes(1);
        iterator.Count += ids.Count();
        return iterator;
    }                      
});

//Output minute group count
Console.WriteLine($"Group count: {deliveryDateGroups.Count}");

//Groups by hour
var byHour = deliveryDateGroups.GroupBy(g => new DateTime(g.ScheduledDateTime.Year, g.ScheduledDateTime.Month, g.ScheduledDateTime.Day, g.ScheduledDateTime.Hour, 0, 0));

Console.WriteLine($"Hour Group count: {byHour.Count()}");
foreach (var group in byHour)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"Date: {group.Key.ToShortDateString()} {group.Key.ToShortTimeString()}; Count: {group.Count()}; Recipients: {group.Sum(g => g.Recipients.Count())}");
}
```

Output:

> Group count: 5556
>
> Hour Group count: 1852
>
> Date: 10/17/2018 12:00 AM; Count: 3; Recipients: 270
>
> Date: 10/17/2018 1:00 AM; Count: 3; Recipients: 270
>
> Date: 10/17/2018 2:00 AM; Count: 3; Recipients: 270
>
> Date: 10/17/2018 3:00 AM; Count: 3; Recipients: 270
>
> Date: 10/17/2018 4:00 AM; Count: 3; Recipients: 270
>
> Date: 10/17/2018 5:00 AM; Count: 3; Recipients: 270
>
> ... and so on for all 1852 groups.

This takes about 3 seconds to complete.

I am sure there are edge cases. I wrote this in a hurry so just think about those.

Comment: WOW! This is a life saving suggestion! and it worked for me with slight changes to respect restriction to work-hours or not. and ALL LOOKS GREAT!
one more thing, the recipients List belongs to one timeZone, what if i have more than one time zone and each one has x number of recipients?
one or more timezone has one start date, so any suggestion how to avoid selecting a date while processing Timezone2 that has already been selected in Timezone 1?
Thanks

Comment: @B.Simboliq: You can always turn this into a function that takes in a master list of delivery dates instead of creating a new one every time (`deliveryDateGroups`), then look into this list prior to adding and advance the delivery date iteration if something is already there. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you. :-)

Comment: Oh Yes sure :) will do that!
but there is one more thing, and please bear with me :), suppose the max per min = 90 and max per hr = 5000 the result of your code is not correct! it assigns 5040 per hour instead of 5000! and I've been trying to solve it since you posted the answer, but i couldn't'! any help or thought?

Comment: this part  `var groupsPerMinute = allRecipients
                    .Select((s, i) => new { Value = s, Index = i })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / maxPerMinute)
                    .Select(group => group.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray());` is only considering the max per min

Comment: @B.Simboliq: I updated the code sample to handle that edge case.

Comment: Thanks! but this change only fixed the FIRST iteration and the rest is still 5040!

Comment: @B.Simboliq: Yes, there was a bug. I updated the last line when adjusting for stragglers. Make sure to create the corresponding constructor in class `GroupIterator'.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) what am i supposed to do with the new parameter passed to the constructor?

Comment: try running the code /before/after the change it gives the same wrong values
  `// Scheduling restrictions 
            int maxPerMinute = 73;
            int maxPerHour = 5000;`

weired!

Comment: ?? any clue? I tried on fixing it but didn't work so far :(

Comment: I've shown you the door my friend, but you must walk through it. The rest is up to you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, but all i wanted to know is what did you mean when added difference to the GroupIterator ?

Comment: @B.Simboliq: The parameter constructor should initialize the count: `return new GroupIterator(newDate, difference);`. This is because you have left overs that need to be accounted for on the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made the necessary changes to it! and now it is supper accurate, it considers the restrictions and if there is any extra stragglers it will handle them till they become 0 ! and also i changed it so it respects the workHours (9 am - 5 pm)
all i have left is modifying it to handle the next timezone scheduling for not having a duplicate date - working on it now

Comment: @B.Simboliq: Awesome. I am glad I was able to help.